# Multiple URLs on multiple lines opened by a single Run command

Tags: autohotkey

As I asked, I want to split this line...

```
<^>!f1::Run chrome.exe http://www.facebook.com http://www.bing.com http://www.twitter.com http://www.surrenderat20.net http://www.youtube.com http://www.hotmail.it http://www.gmail.com
```

... into something like this...

```
<^>!f1::Run chrome.exe
http://www.facebook.com
http://www.bing.com
http://www.twitter.com
http://www.surrenderat20.net
http://www.youtube.com
http://www.hotmail.it
http://www.gmail.com
```

... to make it more readable. Is it possible? It doesn't reloead the code this way, so I'm looking for something that virtually merge into a single line.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [continuation section](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#continuation) in this style. Be sure to leave spaces to the left of any items (to separate them when concatenated).

```
Run, firefox.exe
(
 autohotkey.com
 google.com
)
```